# Problem with show/hide the button and adding a blank object based on input in textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show/hide the "remove" button when a user types in the textbox. Once a user types and removes content, I still want to show the "remove" button.

I am also showing a blank row for the user to add a new employee. Once the user types in the textbox, I want to create a blank row to add a new employee even if the user removes everything from the current row.

I thought of having the "ng-change" event on each of the textboxes but the problem is figuring out the logic for when the user adds/removes anything from a textbox and adding a new row. In my current logic it keeps adding a blank object on every textbox update.

Code:

```html
<table>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="data in myEmployees">
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" ng- change="showRemoveButtonAndCreateNewEmployee(data)" >
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" ng-change="showRemoveButtonAndCreateNewEmployee(data)" ng-model="data.description">
    </td>
    <td class="number-td">
      <input ng-change="showRemoveButtonAndCreateNewEmployee(data)" ng-model="data.age" type="text">
    </td>
    <td ng-show="data.showClose">
      <button>Remove</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I created this Plunker as well :
https://plnkr.co/edit/519FZ2M0rQQcMbEs

I will really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the below...

- Modified the ng-change directive to an ng-click for another 'Add'
  button (to ensure that the entire row is pushed in one go).
- Made the *showClose* toggle to true in the *showRemoveButtonAndCreateNewEmployee*  function before consecutive push.
- The *removeEmployee* function removes the Object.values for the selected row's name (making name a mandated field) - This part could use optimization.
- Also, employeeId remains unhandled.

The below snippet is in no way airtight - however, hope it helps.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.default = true;
  $scope.myEmployees = [];
  $scope.myEmployees.push({
    employeeId: 10, //for blank
    name: 'John',
    description: 'My name is John Dose',
    age: 25,
    showClose: true
  });
  $scope.myEmployees.push({
    employeeId: 11, //for blank
    name: 'Rosa',
    description: 'My name is Rosa',
    age: 26,
    showClose: true
  });
  $scope.myEmployees.push({
    employeeId: null, //for blank
    name: null,
    description: null,
    age: null,
    showClose: false
  });

  $scope.showRemoveButtonAndCreateNewEmployee = function(value, field) {
    value.showClose = true;
    $scope.myEmployees.push(console.log(value));
    $scope.default = false;

  }

  $scope.removeEmployee = function(data, current_name) {

    var i;


    $scope.myEmployees = cleanup($scope.myEmployees);


    for (i = 0; i < Object.values($scope.myEmployees).length; i++) {
      if (Object.values($scope.myEmployees)[i].name === current_name) {
        delete Object.values($scope.myEmployees)[i].employeeId;
        delete Object.values($scope.myEmployees)[i].name;
        delete Object.values($scope.myEmployees)[i].description;
        delete Object.values($scope.myEmployees)[i].age;
        delete Object.values($scope.myEmployees)[i].showClose;
      }
    }

    $scope.myEmployees = Array.from($scope.myEmployees).filter(value => JSON.stringify(value) !== '{}');

    if (!$scope.default)
      $scope.myEmployees.push({
        employeeId: null, //for blank
        name: null,
        description: null,
        age: null,
        showClose: false
      });

  }

  function cleanup() {
    var newArray = Array.from($scope.myEmployees).filter(value => JSON.stringify(value) !== '{}');
    newArray = Array.from($scope.myEmployees).filter(value => JSON.stringify(value) !== undefined);
    return newArray;
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <table id="view">
         <tr data-ng-repeat="data in myEmployees track by $index">
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="data.name"   ></td>
            <td><input type="text"  ng-model="data.description"></td>
            <td class="number-td"><input ng-model="data.age" type="text"></td>
            <td ng-show="!data.showClose" ng-click="showRemoveButtonAndCreateNewEmployee(data,'description')">
               <button>Add</button>
            </td>
            <td ng-show="data.showClose" ng-click="removeEmployee(data,data.name)">
               <button>Remove</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```